# Cannot use right environment database with Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-6

- I have two environment files: `.env` and `.env.dusk.testing` (Because `.env` gets overwritten constantly if I'm not explicit with the environment handler).
- I've got two development servers:

  - One in port `8080` that uses `.env` (using command `php artisan serve --port=8080`)
  - One in port `8000` that uses `.env.dusk.testing` (using command `php artisan serve --env=dusk.testing`)

I'm trying a very basic test. Logging in an user. It's not working because it's not using the correct database.

`.env`

```
APP_NAME=DEV
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5433
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=****
```

`.env.dusk.testing`

```
APP_NAME=DUSK
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

`phpunit.dusk.xml`

```xml
...
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    </php>
...
```

I've also defined the `sqlite` connection in `config/database.php` as follows:

```php
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

My test uses a setup method to wipe up an user and persist it in the database.

```php
namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    protected $user;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'nombre' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'john.doe@testing.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
        ]);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function guest_user_can_authenticate_with_valid_credentials()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->assertGuest()
                    ->visit('/login')
                    ->type('@email', $this->user->email)
                    ->type('@password', 'password')
                    ->click('@login-button')
                    ->assertAuthenticatedAs($this->user)
                    ->assertUrlIs('/dashboard')
                    ->logout();
        });
    }
}
```

Using the `DatabaseMigrations` trait wipes out my PostgreSQL database instead of using the SQLite one. I tried to use `RefreshDatabase` instead but it's the same result. My environment database gets wiped out.

And the test fails anyways in both cases. The user is persisted into the SQLite testing database but it's still looking in the other one in the tests and destroying it in the process.

I'm this close to just drop this package and browser tests altogether. There is nothing simple about it. The documentation is shallow and it just doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I think the complication is by having the two servers running. How does Dusk know which one to use?

Comment: I thought so too but dusk just goes for the default (127.0.0.1:8000). Having both servers running or just 1 running isn't a factor.

Comment: If you make a page that just prints out `APP_NAME` from the env, does it confirm it is using the correct settings? When the migrations are run for example, is it also confirming the correct settings?

Comment: It doesn't. It turns out the environment file just wasn't being used. If I tried to make a `.env.dusk` file, the test suite ran with the original `.env` file BEFORE overwriting it. I had to be explicit and run `php artisan dusk` with the `--env` parameter to finally make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue was fixed by

- Not using an in-memory SQLite database (I used a `.sqlite` file instead).
- Using the `DatabaseMigrations` trait instead of `RefreshDatabase`.
- Being explicit about the environment file when running dusk. `php artisan dusk --env=dusk.testing`.

Comment: can you share some of your sqlite + dusk use cases? I am wondering if adding this can save us some round trips of setup to other apps to get data set up a certain way for order pages/ product pages but i can find hardly any non user log in sqlite examples

Comment: It's lost I'm afraid. This question is 2.5 years old. I was using Laravel 6 back then so most of this is not relevant today. I don't think using sqlite + dusk is much of a time save.